# groovysh crashes under Java 1.7.0_75 (Windows XP)

Tags: groovy

Using the latest version of Groovy (as of this writing), 2.4.0, and Windows XP (sp3), I have encountered a familiar but perplexing error:

```
    C:\>groovysh
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java
:106)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: leftPadding f
or class: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.HelpFormatter
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptByteco
deAdapter.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProp
erty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:532)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.HelpFormatter.<init>(HelpFormatt
er.groovy:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstru
ctor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteN
oUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstru
ctor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor
(AbstractCallSite.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor
(AbstractCallSite.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main.main(Main.groovy:68)
        ... 6 more
```

I experienced no difficulty using Groovy 2.3.9 so I was wondering if anyone had a constructive suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: in sep 2014 the missing `leftPadding` there was introduced.  are you sure you are not mixing your two installations?

Comment: I deleted the previous install of Groovy (2.3.9), the GROOVY_HOME variable is set and my path variable reads: C:\groovy-2.4.0\bin. I can run and compile groovy programs without a problem yet the aforementioned issue with groovysh remains. Could it be an entry on the classpath? Perhaps a .jar file for another program, e.g., clojure-1.6.0.jar? I can also compile and run java programs without difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Error occurs in the HelpFormatter class. The sources can be found via google, i.e. here:
https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-groovysh/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/shell/util/HelpFormatter.groovy

As you can see, class HelpFormatter extends org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter

And expects the superclass to have a field leftPadding, but does not find one.

This could be the case if you have a different version of apache commons-cli.jar on your CLASSPATH when running groovysh.

Since I cannot reproduce your problem, this is the most likely cause I can see.

Run

echo %CLASSPATH

in Windows to see the CLASSPATh (I think).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have reduced my CLASSPATH setting to the more condensed: .;C:\lein;C:\lein\bin;C:\progra~1\scala\bin;C:\atomicscala\examples yet the problem remains. I have no idea what library might contain the apache commons-cli code. Could it be the case that Groovy 2.4.0 is not fully compatible with jdk 1.7.0_75 since this is a very new update (as is 2.4.0 for groovy)?

Comment: I have no difficulty in starting groovysh if I set my current working directory to C:\groovy-2.4.0 or C:\groovy-2.4.0\bin. Since the latter is the second entry on my PATH, after '.', the problem is proving to be both perplexing and frustrating.